# Convert/generate the keystore file from the csr file?

Tags: ssl, keystore, csr

To apply a certificate, first I created a keystore file and then a csr file. Then I pass the csr file to the signing authority to request a certificate. Signing authority provided me the certificate, now I need to import the certificate into keystore file. But unfortunately I have lost the originally generated keystore file, but I have the csr file.

My Question: Is there any way to convert/generate the original keystore file from the csr file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure, but may be with the help of 'keytool' command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot**. The `CSR` only contains `PublicKey`.

It is explained [here](http://www.rainydayz.org/content/1015-i-lost-my-passphrase-my-key-pair-my-private-key) and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24491/is-it-possible-to-regenerate-my-private-key-ssl).

You can check with the Certificate Authority if they can reissue a new Certificate for a new request.

Comment: OK Thanks. As you suggested I am creating a new keystore/csr and sending it to Certificate Authority.