# I've deleted my keystore. Now what?

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, keytool, csr

I've generated a csr file and send it to a CA to sign and generate a certificate.

I have the certificate now, but accidentally I've deleted the keystore that have created the csr file earlier.

So, my question is can I create another keystore and import the certificates into it in order to use with a weblogic server or do I need to repeat all the process from the very beginning and ask the CA for a new certificate?

Comment: The keystore had one and only copy of the private key. Start over.

Comment: You **cannot**. More info can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751546/convert-generate-the-keystore-file-from-the-csr-file).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry over your loss.But you have to start the process all over again or you can generate an self signed certificate using openssl for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

> Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

- There's no way to recover your key.
- So finally, Its not possible. Please Create new keystore with the application with different package name and version and publish as a new application.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing for more details